# I want to join data and display all records from one table and just one record from another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am a Codeigniter developer. I am working on an e-commerce site. I face one issue in the admin panel. I have two tables 
table_1= tbl_category
table_2= tbl_products

I want to update a product. I fetch all data of product from tbl_products using this:

```
$this->db->select('*')
         ->from('tbl_products')
         ->where('cat_id,$id)
         ->get();
```

It is working perfect but I want to display a dropdown of all categories in the update product page. The problem is I can't find a solution how I can do it. I have to fetch one product by its id from tbl product but how to fetch all categories. I want a solution in Codeigniter. I will wait for your answers Please help me, friends.

Comment: You need to pass another query parameter to the upload page. You need to write a query to get all category data from tables table_1= tbl_category and pass that query param in  the view page. Its simple.

Answer (score 0):

you better remove the where clause or remove cat_id from where clause like:

```
$this->db->select('*')
         ->from('tbl_products')
         ->where('cat_id,$id) //remove where clause or remove cat_id
         ->get();
```

so that you will get all the categories selected

if u want to display data from other table having a foreign key then use left join on the keys

Comment: if u want to display data from other table having a foreign key then use left join

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*')
         ->from('tbl_products')
        ->join('tbl_category','tbl_category.id = tbl_products.id')
         ->get();
```

Comment: can you please add some explanation to your answer? It will be very useful to understand what you are suggesting to do...

Comment: But I want to fetch every record from tbl_category and just one row from tbl_product